# attach pivot table to other two tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, pivot-table

I have 2 tables. One with users and one with locations. I created a pivot table called user_locations. A user can have one or more locations. A location can belong to one or more users. So i'm having a many to many relation on these tables. I've read about the attach method from laravel but i'm not quite sure on how to use it.

In my user and locations table i have an id which both go into my pivot table under user_id and location_id.

```
$user = new User;
$user->organisation_id = Auth::user()->organisation_id;
$user->fill(Input::except('locations'));

$input_locations = Input::only('locations');

foreach($input_locations as $input_location){
$location_id = Location::where('name', '=', $input_location)->get();
$location = Location::find($location_id);

$user->User_location()->associate($location);
```

There are at this moment two problems that i'm running into. In Location::where('name... I should check on the id from $input_locations but I don't know how to get the id? There is an id and a name coming from Input::only('locations').

My second problem is the last line of code. Here I should use attach. I found this in laravel docs:

You may also pass an array of attributes that should be stored on the pivot table for the relation:

```
 $user->roles()->attach(1, array('expires' => $expires));
```

So what I think it should be is something like this:

```
 $user->user_locations()->attach(the new user id, array('location_id' => $location_id));
```

Really hope someone can help me out because I really don't know on to go from here.

**UPDATE:**

This is my user controller:

```
 public function createUserPost()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->organisation_id = Auth::user()->organisation_id;
    $user->fill(Input::except('locations'));

    // pak het field locations
    $input_locations = Input::only('locations');

    if($user->save())
    {
        // Koppel de id's van de locatie aan de nieuwe user
        $new_user_id = $user->id;
        foreach ($input_locations as $key => $value) {
            $location = Location::find($value);
            User::find($new_user_id)->locations()->attach($location);
        }
        return Redirect::to('users/'.$user->id);
    }
    return $this->createUser($user);
}
```

In my user model I have this rule:

```
 'locations' => 'required',
```

This is needed because it is a required field. Now when I hit the submit button it doesn't save the user but says the field "locations" is required while it is filled. The problem is that the name of the select is locations. But I don't know how to get this into my table because I don't a column called locations. This is just needed to fill my pivot table and make sure the field is required within the form.

Comment: Why do you even have a `locations` column in your User model? You shouldn't! I don't understand the use of that column.

Comment: No I don't have a column locations there. But the form uses the rules of the model user. How can I also use the rules from the locations model? If 'locations' => 'required' should be put there if I understand you correctly

Comment: A rule should be for the columns of the model you are setting the rules for.  So a user model should not have location rules since the model doesn't have any location.  You should define the location rules in the location model.  Upon saving,  perform the validation on both models and proceed if both pass

Comment: I don't have access to a computer right now. I suggest you read Jeffery Way Laravel validation tutorial on how to use them effectively

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all the help. It all works now. Only problem is the password field. Somehow it doesn't post the password field.

Comment: Read the authentication on Laravel documentation.  You need to `Hash` the password and save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [Laravel's Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)?

You want a Many-to-Many relationship. In that case, rename your pivot table to `location_user` (By default it should be alphabetical).

Then define your relationships:

```
// In User.php model
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name']; \\ List of all allowable items to be filled

public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Location');
}

// In Location.php model
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}
```

After that, there are many ways to attach a `Location` to your `User`. Best way would be:

```
public function createUserPost()
{
    $user = new User(Input::all); // Use the $fillable in the model to allow mass assign

    // This should be done via a relationship
    $user->organisation_id = Auth::user()->organisation_id;

    // pak het field locations
    $input_locations = Input::only('locations');

    $location_ids = [];
    foreach($input_locations as $key => $id) {
        $location_ids[] = Location::find($value)->id;
    }
    $user->locations()->attach($location_ids);

    if($user->save())
    ...
}
```

Comment: But a user can be assigned to more than one location. So that's why i need a pivot table.

Comment: I'm doing while creating a user. Can I do it like so: $user->locations()->attach($location)? And this in an foreach for each location

Comment: Create your user firs (i.e. `save()`) and then `attach($location)`

Comment: Okey but then I run into another problem. I use laravel form validation with rules. So my form is openend like this: 
     {{ Form::model($user) }}
In the rules of user I have that location is required. But somehow it doesn't save and says that location is required.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you explain please?

Comment: I modified the code slightly. You should use http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment to allow safe mass assignment.

Comment: I'm allready using fillable. I'm getting the following error: 
BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::location()

Comment: Make sure spelling is correct. I wrote  `locations()` with an some.